# Select rows only if having row number partition count equals to specific value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a temporary table (from Stored Procedure) named TEMP1 as follows:

| Rnk (Row Number Partition by DocNo) | DocNo | TransDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc1 | 1 Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Doc1 | 2 Aug 2023 |
| 3 | Doc1 | 3 Aug 2023 |
| 1 | Doc2 | 4 Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Doc2 | 5 Aug 2023 |
| 1 | Doc3 | 6 Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Doc3 | 7 Aug 2023 |
| 3 | Doc3 | 8 Aug 2023 |
| 1 | Doc4 | 9 Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Doc4 | 10 Aug 2023 |
| 3 | Doc4 | 11 Aug 2023 |

I need to retrieve rows which have full Rnk (1 to 3) and TransDate for Rnk 3 is in a specific range.
For example, if I set TransDate range condition from 1 Aug 2023 to 10 Aug 2023, then it will return:

| Rnk (Row Number Partition by DocNo) | DocNo | TransDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc1 | 1 Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Doc1 | 2 Aug 2023 |
| 3 | Doc1 | 3 Aug 2023 |
| 1 | Doc3 | 6 Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Doc3 | 7 Aug 2023 |
| 3 | Doc3 | 8 Aug 2023 |

How do I get these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach, using a CTE with conditional aggregation:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN Rnk = 3 AND
                              TransDate BETWEEN '20230801' AND '20230810'
                         THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNo) AS cnt
    FROM tempTable
)

SELECT Rnk, DocNo, TransDate
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 0
ORDER BY DocNo, Rnk;
```

The `cnt` in the subquery will be greater than zero if there exist, for a given collection of documents in the same `DocNo`, a rank 3 record in the correct date range.

Answer (score -2):

One method would be to use a CTE with a conditional windowed `MAX` to get the value of `TransDate` when the value of `Rnk` is `3` and the fitler on the value of that value in the outer query:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Rnk,
           DocNo,
           TransDate,
           MAX(CASE Rnk WHEN 3 THEN TransDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNo) AS Rnk3TransDate
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Doc1',TRY_CONVERT(date,'1 Aug 2023')),
                (2,'Doc1',TRY_CONVERT(date,'2 Aug 2023')),
                (3,'Doc1',TRY_CONVERT(date,'3 Aug 2023')),
                (1,'Doc2',TRY_CONVERT(date,'4 Aug 2023')),
                (2,'Doc2',TRY_CONVERT(date,'5 Aug 2023')),
                (1,'Doc3',TRY_CONVERT(date,'6 Aug 2023')),
                (2,'Doc3',TRY_CONVERT(date,'7 Aug 2023')),
                (3,'Doc3',TRY_CONVERT(date,'8 Aug 2023')),
                (1,'Doc4',TRY_CONVERT(date,'9 Aug 2023')),
                (2,'Doc4',TRY_CONVERT(date,'10 Aug 2023')),
                (3,'Doc4',TRY_CONVERT(date,'11 Aug 2023')))V(Rnk,DocNo,TransDate))
SELECT Rnk,
       DocNo,
       TransDate
FROM CTE
WHERE Rnk3TransDate >= '20230801' AND Rnk3TransDate < '20230811';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uUGGPINr)